# string.Format "C" (currency) is returning the string "C" instead of formatted text

Tags: c#, format

I am trying to ensure that the text in my control derived from TextBox is always formatted as currency.

I have overridden the Text property like this.

```
   public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {                
            double tempDollarAmount = 0;
            string tempVal = value.Replace("$", "").Replace(",","");
            if (double.TryParse(tempVal, out tempDollarAmount))
            {
                base.Text = string.Format("C", tempDollarAmount);
            }
            else
            {                 
                base.Text = "$0.00";
            }                
        }
    }
```

Results:

- If I pass the value "Text"
  (AmountControl.Text = "Text";) , the
  text of the control on my test page
  is set to "$0.00", as expected.
- If I pass the value 7
  (AmountControl.Text = "7";) , I
  expect to see "$7.00", but the text
  of the control on my test page is set
  to "C".

I assume that I am missing something very simple here. Is it something about the property? Or am I using the string format method incorrectly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of "C" put "{0:c}"

For more string formatting problems go [here](http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Comment: Thanks. I marked this as the answer, since you're first. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use tempDollarAmount.ToString("C").

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I'm glad to see how the "C" format string is actually used.

Comment: I personally think this is a better method, any confirm which is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Needs to be "{0:C}"

Answer (score 1):

it should be "{0:C}"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be:

```
base.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", tempDollarAmount);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
base.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", tempDollarAmount);
```

And please don't use double to represent currency, use decimal instead.

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("The value 99999 in various Format");
String s = "$";
String s1=s.Replace(s,"RS");
String s2 = String.Format("{0:c}", s1);
String s3="1000";
Console.WriteLine(s2 + s3);
```

Comment: Hey, don't do that. It dilutes the real answers.